# Extend Partition To Entire Drive

Tags: grub2, partitioning, gparted

I am currently dual booting Win 10 and Ubuntu, in order for me to try it out and ensure I could get the exact same functionality from my Ubuntu install that I could from Windows (I know they are not the same, I mean I could still complete my day to day tasks).

Well now the test time is over, and I want to eradicate the Win 10 partition, and extend my Ubuntu partition across the entire drive.  My set-up is like so

```
sd1 = Win 10
sd2 = Ubuntu
```

What do I need to do in order to delete the sda partition then extend the sdb partition to utilize the free space?

**EDIT**
Neither partition is encrypted, and LVM was not used for either partition. (if either of that matters)

**EDIT 2**
The results of `blkid` are below

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="72e0f0d2-ee76-47b4-ad05-d2b0dc20def6" TYPE="NTFS" PARTUUID="47d165c3-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="d7e4cf38-fa21-4444-aeab-900264828966" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="47d165c3-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="c7ea18a5-547e-4aed-b28d-a895dbe8855f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="47d165c3-06"
```

Comment: well you have something wrong in your explanation because if you have sda and sdb then you have 2 hard drives and there is no way to do what you want unless you completely reinstall Ubuntu and use LVM to span the drives.(i think .. not real sure about LVM) do a `sudo blkid`and add that to your question so we can have a better idea of your drive layout

Comment: @JohnOrion - not in front of this specific PC atm, I apologize, they are both on the same disk and my Ubuntu partition does in fact come second.  I will give output of that command as soon as I can.

Comment: ok .. yeah we kinda need it because there are probably more partitions in there too .. there will be a recovery partition for windows and a swap partition for Linux. You will most likely be able to use gparted to remove the windows partitions and expand the Ubuntu one but .. it will depend on the layout of the other partitions as to if it would be wise to do it or not

Comment: Best to just post partitions `sudo parted -l`. I do not like moving partitions left. That is a complete copy and any interuption power failure totaly corrupts system and you have to reinstall & restore from backup. I might suggest just using NTFS partition as a data partition, but reformat (erasing data) to ext4. If you keep it as NTFS you must have a Windows repair disk to run chkdsk occasionally.

Comment: @JohnOrion - see edit.   Reults of blkid have been posted.

Comment: The blkid, shows partitions, but not necessarily order on drive. But it looks like you have swap in between sda1  & sda6. And sda5 & sda6 as logical partitions will be inside an extended partition where sda1 is a primary partition outside the extended. Gets more complicated. Still easier to use as a data partition.

Comment: @oldfred - ugh, I was hoping it would be simple as delete unwanted, extend what I want to keep! --- I believe the partition I want to keep is roughly 60GB, could I clone this partition only to an external drive, wipe this drive, then image the drive from the clone I made to the external?

Comment: That probably would work. But I have always preferred backup your data, /home, /etc and export list of installed apps. That already should be your normal backup anyway. And just reinstall. Restore /home, do not restore /etc but review if you had manually edited anything. And restore list of installed apps.

Answer (score 0):

The conceptually simple way to do this is to back up your data and install Ubuntu clean with "use the entire disk" option, then restore data from backup.  This isn't the way I'd do it, for a number of reasons, but it's surely the easiest way to do the partition changes you want.

Otherwise, you're going to have problems.  Deleting the first (or first two or three) partitions on the hard disk and expanding the remaining one(s) to fill the space is going to cause problems with partition ordering; you may get away with it if you (or your installer) used UUID for all your GRUB and `fstab` designations, but the first partition or two are almost certainly primary partitions, and my experience is that only logical volumes located inside an extended partition can be readily relocated or expanded.

One reasonably practical way to do this, however, might be to delete the Windows partition(s) (using a partitioning tool from inside Ubuntu or Ubuntu Live), create new partition(s), and clone the Ubuntu partition into the new partition(s).  You'll need to correct the UUIDs in GRUB and `fstab`, but this will get Ubuntu into the primary partition(s) and let you do what you like with the rest of the hard disk space.

It should go without saying, that you should make a backup of anything you want to keep before attempting this...